# Invalid Hadoop Runtime specified - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, ubuntu-14.04

I recently configured Hadoop 2.6.0 in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Virtual machine. Now I need to be able to write MapReduce jobs in Eclipse. FOr that, I have downloaded Eclipse Europa 3.3.1.

The problem is when I start a Map/Reduce project, it gives this error and doesn't go forward. Please help. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on "Configure Hadoop install directory" and provide the directory where the mapreduce JARs are - it should be something like:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/2.6.0/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce
```

Answer (score -1):

Click on `Configure Hadoop install directory...` and configure it.

Comment: What path do I give it?

Comment: The path where you installed Hadoop. Maybe /usr/local/hadoop

Comment: It isn't accepting this path. The error persists. The installation directory is however the same i.e /usr/local/hadoop.